# pycharm doesn't recognize pygame package

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I'm using `mac OsX 10.8.2`, `pyCharm 2.7.1`. `python 2.7.2`

I want to use `pygame` package with `pycharm`. I followed the instructions on the `pygame` site and installed pygame 1.9.1 successfully. 
When I write "import pygame" pycharm doesn't find the package.

I tried installing the latest updates of python, pycharm and pygame. I tried using the "install" window in the preferences. It installed "pygamess", "pygameui" and "pyviewx.pygame", but when I try to instal "pygame_loaders" it writes "Install packages failed: Error occurred when installing package pygame_loaders".

If you can please give simple instruction since I'm not a heavy mac-user.

Answer (score 4):

To use pygame under OS X, you need to run Python under the 32 bit interpreter. It's usually called something like 'python2.7-32', and if installed from the package on http://www.python.org/, within /usr/local/bin

To get this working in PyCharm, open a project, then preferences ('apple'-'comma'), go to 'python interpreters', and click the '+' button in the right hand pane.

A list should appear and you'll see '/usr/local/bin/python2.7-32', select that and then make it the default for your PyGame project.

If you haven't installed Python from python.org, I recommend you do so; the current version is 2.7.3.

The above setup is how I got PyGame working in PyCharm on Sunday, so it should still be valid.

Comment: In PyCharm 3.4, it's now `Project Interpreter` instead of `python interpreters`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 2.7 virtualenvs running inside pyCharm you can manual install pygame.
Navigate to the virtual env on you disk via the terminal:

```
cd ~/.virtualenvs/Pygame
```

Or whatever directory you have. Now we active the virtualenv, just like we normal do when we not work inside pyCharm.

```
source ./bin/acivate
```

You should see something like this

```
(Pygame)mbp-2:Pygame pietje$
```

Now we can install pygame inside this env.

```
pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

That's it and everything should work fine inside PyCharm. It does work on my machine :)